# aggregate() with weighted mean in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, weighted-average

I have a dataset like this:

```
data.frame(car brand, car model, car sold, co2 emission)
```

And I want to get the total nb sold per car brand. So I did this:

```
x <- aggregate(carsold ~ carbrand, data=data.frame, FUN=sum)
```

Then, I want to get the average co2 emission per car brand.

```
y <- aggregate(co2emission ~ carbrand, data=data.frame, FUN=mean)
```

And finally I merge x and y

```
z <- merge(x, y, by="carbrand")
```

So I get this

```
data.frame(car brand, nb sold, average co2 emission)
```

Problem: in the dataset, nb of car sold may be different for each item. So sometimes, for one model I have 3 cars sold with a certain co2 emission, sometimes 1.

How can I aggregate the nb of car sold per car brand with the **weighted** average of co2 emission ?

Thanks

Comment: Check out `?weighted.mean`.

Comment: This is not making any sense. Where is the weighting supposed to be applied? You wouldn't divide the car-model-CO2-means again by the number of cars sold. The division has already been done.

Comment: BondedDust: I know I'm wrong. But is there a way to compute weighted average of co2 emission regarding number of car sold for each car brand (car brand level, not car model) ?

Comment: The values of (nb_sold * average_co2_emission) for each brand should give you what you want.